# web (server) based password manager

Tags: password-management

I know there have been a few topics here about password managers but I read them all and did not really find what I'm looking for.

What I'd need is a free or cheap (most password mgr software is $500 for 20+ users, exaggerated!) multi-user password manager, **highly preferable web-based** so that we can host it on one of our local server.

So:
-free or cheap ( <100$)
-multi-user of groups
-web based
-not very hard to install

I tried a few, one very expensive, one I did not get to work-> Web Keepass Manager
This works with tomcat and probably conflicts with our IIS 7.0 or 7.5

PS: thus, nothing online (!) it has to stay local

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe it'll be cheaper and more handy to develop a private solution :)

Comment: Yes probably, I'll definitely skip webkeepass. I set it up in debian again but it's too slow and -for me- it's quite unpredictable.
And it doesn't work with FF3.5; I'll make something myself in php or so. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Someone else asked, basically, the same question and it is getting more traction...

[Company Password Management](https://serverfault.com/questions/119892/company-password-management)

Answer (score -4):

[WebKeePass](http://ossfree.net/webkeepass/) (Free, Apache Tomcat/MySQL)

;)

Comment: He mentioned that he tried this one

Comment: Oh, really. Password management software is very simple, it's strange that there are such a few of them.